# Add date in timestamp MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

Add date in timestamp

I want to run below query

```
UPDATE table
SET columnA = '2017-03-21 23:57:19'
WHERE .....
```

However, I want to construct the timestamp by taking whatever yesterday's date is, at `23:57:19` hours.

The datatype for `columnA` is `timestamp`.  `2017-03-21` is yesterday's date.  Am I supposed to use `subdate(CURDATE(),1)`?

```
UPDATE table
SET columnA = 'subdate(CURDATE(),1) 23:57:19' WHERE .....  ?
```

Or I have another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
UPDATE table
SET columnA = DATE_SUB('2017-03-22 23:57:19', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

or

```
UPDATE table
SET columnA = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

If you wanted to get yesterday at `23:57:19` then try this:

```
DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)), INTERVAL '23:57:19' HOUR_SECOND)

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) - yesterday's date
TIMESTAMP(...)                      - resets yesterday to midnight
DATE_ADD(..., INTERVAL '23:57:19')  - adds 23:57:19 to yesterday from midnight
```

## Demo

Comment: @GurV Yes, there is certainly a [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub), check the documentation :-)

Comment: Then how about `23:57:19` ?

Comment: Assume today is `2017-03-24` and I want to set to `2017-03-23`, how can I use the first option since it is not always `2017-03-22`

Comment: I have met your requirements as far as I can tell.

Comment: `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` gives yesterday's date

Comment: OK, so should be something like this ? `DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL '23:57:19' HOUR_SECOND)` ?

Comment: I don't think that will run.  Are you trying to get `23:57:19` on _yesterday_ ?

Comment: Yes, the date should be yesterday and min/hours always 23:57:19

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get  `2017-03-22 13:24:12`, seems like current date and time

Comment: I have it working now, try the demo if you have any questions.